# Control over the order of elements in XSD sequence while generating XSD in Enterprise Architect

Tags: xsd, enterprise-architect

I tried but I can't find any property to control the order of elements in a **XSD Sequence** element in while generating XSD in Enterprise Architect.

I'd appreciate if you could shed some light on this :)

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

From the "Profile for XML Schema" topic in the help file, there's a tag associated with <<XSDelement>> named **position**:

*"Causes the elements to be ordered within a sequence model group of the containing complexType. Duplicated and invalid position Tagged Values are ignored and result in undefined ordering of the UML attributes. Missing position values cause the defined positions to be allocated as specified, with the remaining elements filling the missing positions in an undefined order.
"*